# PCB Switch for 5V and a few amps

Tags: power-supply, switches

Looking at slide switches to put on a PCB I've noticed that most are rated for multiple amps of AC current; however, they can only switch 100mA of DC current.  I need to switch 2.5A of 5V DC current.  Am I just looking at the wrong type of switches, am I misunderstanding the spec, or are there no normal sized slide switches for DC current (that I can put on a PCB)?  Looking at some of my dev boards, my ZED board has a switch that is definitely switching more than an amp, but looking at the data sheet for it it says it is only rated for 100mA of DC.

What is the right way for switching 5V/2.5A on and off on a PCB board?

Comment: Where are you looking?  I'm seeing over 100 slide switches that are 3A+ DC on Digikey.

Comment: 100mA DC at what voltage?

Comment: @vir, I am probably looking at it wrong, but on digikey I look for a switch with 3A(DC) in the slide switch category.  I find this one: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/e-switch/500SSP1S1M6QEA/378947  which has a 5A rating, but looking at the data sheet it really is 0.4VA for DC, so for 5V it is under 100mA.  Or am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: That datasheet is listing the gold and silver contact plating ratings.  The "Q" in that part number designates silver plating, which is 5A at 120VAC or 28VDC.  If the part number were 500SSP1S1M6**R**EA, you would be at the 0.4VA limit.  It's not listed on there, but silver plated contacts have a *minimum* current rating to prevent the formation of insulating oxides on the surfaces, usually a few dozen to a few hundred mA.  See e.g.: https://www.nidec-copal-electronics.com/e/catalog/switch/8ss.pdf